# ebx в стэковом фрейме

Tags: c, ассемблер, стек

```
global  sys_read
global  sys_write
global  sys_errno

section .text
syscall_3:      push    ebp
                mov     ebp, esp
                **push    ebx**
                mov     ebx, [ebp+8]
                mov     ecx, [ebp+12]
                mov     edx, [ebp+16]
                int     80h
                mov     ebx, eax
                and     ebx, 0xfffff000
                cmp     ebx, 0xfffff000
                jnz     .okay
                mov     [sys_errno], eax
                mov     eax, -1
.okay:          **pop     ebx**
                mov     esp, ebp
                pop     ebp
                ret

sys_read:       mov     eax, 3
                jmp     syscall_3

sys_write:      mov     eax, 4
                jmp     syscall_3

section .bss
sys_errno       resd    1
```

Это реализации функций read и write для С, что бы не использовать стандартную библиотеку.

Вот хоть убейте, но я не могу понять зачем в стековом фрейме сохраняется значение из EBX (push ebx)???, там изначально 0 при первом вызове любой из функций, так же потом pop извлекает этот 0 в тот же ebx...

есть вызовы:

```
sys_read(0, х, size);
sys_write(1, x, size);
```

Без этих push ebx и pop ebx строка после ввода не распечатается. Попробуйте объяснить, пожалуйста.

Comment: По соглашению вызова stdcall (и схожим соглашениям) значение ebx после выхода из функции должно быть таким же как и при входе в нее. Т.к. в функции его значение меняется, значит старое значение нужно сохранить, а перед выходом из функции восстановить. Если функция соблюдает это соглашение, то вы можете хранить в этом регистре, например, счетчик, и не бояться, что при вызове этой функции значение этого регистра будет испорчено.

Comment: @insolor, у меня 2 вызова. Первый что-то сделал с ebx и второй что-то сделал с ebx по своему. Сделали они это по очереди и после первого вызова второй вызов не нуждается в старом значении ebx. Следственно - я все равно не понял (

Comment: Вы забываете, что вашу функцию тоже кто-то вызывает (операционная система, например, или какая-то другая программа), и вызывающая сторона тоже должна быть уверена, что регистр ebx не будет испорчен.

Comment: @insolor, да! Я только об этом подумал и gdb запустил, там между вызовами есть ebx в работе. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос исчерпан. Ответ на него в комментариях под вопросом, спасибо.

Вкратце: по конвенции CDECL(и еще каких-то там) можно в вызываемых подпрограммах(функциях/процедурах) испортить регистры eax, edx, ecx. Остальные регистры могут быть уже в работе ОС или в других функциях, следовательно - их нужно восстановить перед возвратом из функции, которая их использовала.